# log4j2 ERROR exception adding carriage returns?

Tags: java, linux, log4j

I'm using the log4j exception logging syntax like

```
log.error("Exception: ", e);
```

Seems to me the log4j is inserting a carriage return to separate the message and the throwable. Can see the circled ^M below. Anyone know how I could have that log as a normal newline instead? (so it would look like logging statement preceding it)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the stacktrace, I believe that is the expected output. If you want the exception message itself, you can access it with `e.getMessage()`. In your case, you could eliminate the `Exception:` string as you're already logging it at the error level and log it as `log.error(e.getMessage(), e)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know how I could have that log as a normal newline instead?

You could construct the message yourself and pass that message as the sole argument to the `log.error(...)` method. As it is, you are passing 2 parameters, a message and a `Throwable`.  The message is written to the log output, and the the stack trace is written as a separate thing.  That is by design and what most folks want.  If that is not what you want, don't pass the `Throwable` and construct your own message.